# Join on column with different format

Tags: sql

Is it possible to join on the following:

```
table1
imdb_id ==> '12345'

table2
imdb_url ==> 'http://imdb.com/title/tt0012345/'
```

And then I'd want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 join table2 USING (**imdb**)
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Note: Any time you join based on a predicate it's computed meaning simple `ColumnAValue = ColumnBValue` are trivial solved but `Function(ValueA) = ValueB` ill force the computation for every `AXB` pair and worst: ill hinder any index at ColumnA. That's a common performance hog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from table1
join table2 on table2.imdb_url like '%' + table1.imdb_id + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `oracle`, you can extract the `number` part from the url using `regexp` and match it.

```
select * from table1
join table2 on
table1.imdb_id = cast(regexp_replace(t2.imdb_url, '\D') as numeric)
```